# Spark driver/executor doesn't allow logging of Prometheus Jmx-exporter's fine logs that is should output as JMX-agent

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus, javaagents, jmx-exporter, google-spark-operator

The java process is called as:

```
  /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java -XX:+UseG1GC -Dlog4j.debug 
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/metrics/conf/logging.properties 
-javaagent:/prometheus/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=8090:/etc/metrics/conf/prometheus.yaml
 -Dspark.driver.port=7078 -Dspark.driver.blockManager.port=7079 -Xms1g -Xmx1g 
-cp /etc/hadoop/conf::/opt/spark/jars/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/etc/hadoop/conf:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/* org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend 
--driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@realtimesummariesjob-f1c1217b63219e7f-driver-svc.spark-apps.svc:7078
 --executor-id 1 --cores 1 --app-id spark-fcab57dc38254481a12bdd9dc79b7a98 --hostname 10.244.1.23
```

so it has prometheus JMX-exporter to be set up as javaagent. And logging is set up according to the https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter#debugging

However, no one from prometheus jmx-exporter log is observed. JMX-exporter itself works correctly and outputs the correctly formatted data on the exposed port.

What is the way to provide the logging for the code that is executed as javaagent?